# Simple date format for string behaving erratically

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

To give you an overview, we have an MDB application on which we receive transactions throughout the day. One of the column in the feed is a date in the format ddmmyyyy hhmiss. We are trying to parse it through the SimpleDateFormat (java api) so that we could parse the string to a date object to insert into a table.

What is happening is that in some cases my date is moved to a previous date. The observation was that it has moved back by 5-6 hours causing the transaction to become a BVT although it was not.
For eg: One of the transactions had arrived as 24th Sept 12:01 am GMT, but in the table it was inserted as 23rd Sep 7:30pm.

I would also like you to note that the servers are in Chicago. So is it that it is considering the server time since there is almost a time difference of 5-6 hours between London and Chicago?

The code snippet is a below:

```
SimpleDateFormat lDtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss");
Timestamp lDtmp = new java.sql.Timestamp(lDtFormat.parse(strParseString).getTime());
```

Now my question is should i be changing the above code by passing a locale to the constructor.

```
SimpleDateFormat lDtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss",Locale.UK);
```

Would the above code snippet fix the issue?

Is it that now after setting the locale it would not convert the time and eventually the date ?

Answer (score 1):

Giving the local explicitly in the constructor of SimpleDateFormat is not sufficient. Its purpose is mainly to support formatting or parsing of localized strings like "March" (english), "Maart" (dutch) etc.

You also need to set the time zone in SimpleDateFormat, here probably the time zone of London like this:

```
lDtFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
```

You should also check if the time zone on the server should not better be configured to UTC ("GMT") in your scenario of international date and time exchange.